# Problems with Listpicker App Inventor

Tags: android, app-inventor

I'm a beginner at App Inventor and I don't know what I'm doing wrong with the `listpicker`.
I am trying to create and app to reproduce the music I have stored in my server but when i display the `listpicker` I can't click any of the options and also I can't go back to the first screen. Here I put my code:

Image 1
[image]
Image 2
[image]

I tried to remove the line that says `call listpicker.open` but it only made appear a totally black screen.
The result of the code I just posted is exactly what I spect a list with the name and the link of the 2 songs I already upload to my server but when I click them it didn't do anything.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Web` component works asynchronously, which means, it takes a little bit, until the result is available. The result you will get in the `Web.GotText` event.

Therefore it does not make sense to call the `updateListpicker` procedure in the `Listpicker.BeforePicking` event, because the result still is not available and you get displayed an empty listpicker. The listpicker will be opened, before you have received the result!

**Set the listpicker to visible=false and use a button.click event to call the `updateListpicker` procedure.** Then as you already do it in the `Web.GotText` event, assign the received list to the listpicker and open it.

Comment: Thanks Taifun, that works perfectly. The problem is that I want that the listpicker opens when the app starts, thats why I put the procedure in the Listpicker.BeforePicking, and I'm wondering if there is a control object called on start or that make the updateListpicker trigger without the user clicking any button.
Also I want thanks you for correcting my misspels.

Comment: in this case put your `updateListpicker` procedure call into the `Screen.Initialize` event...

Comment: btw. see also here how stackoverflow works: [What does it mean to accept an answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Thanks again Taifun I accepted you answer but unfortunately I don't have 15 reputations points to vote. But don't worry I will do it when I have enough.